# HTTPS Connection error

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to a servlet from usinghttp url connection,i.e http://localhost:9481/test/NewServlet. It worked fine for me. Now I want to connect using https://localhost:9481/test/NewServlet. I got the error like :

```
Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long,Connection refused...
```

Do I need to edit anything in server.xml :

Presently it looks like:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: Hi user10101, welcome to [security.se]! Please take a moment to read the [FAQ], and also [ask]. I think there is some missing information, context etc. As @Karrax noted, this may be better on [so], unless it is specifically about security. How to develop and configure your application would be offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

I will still answer this, even if it is offtopic.

The problem seems to be that even if you are changing to HTTPS you are not changing the port number to 8443. The probable reason your browser is complaining is that you are servered normal HTTP content over what the browser would think would be HTTP protocol.

Change to port 8443 and try again.

Comment: I have tried it,it did not worked.I forgot to post it.

Comment: What web or application-server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache..

Comment: Apache Tomcat I presume?

Comment: Yes Apache Tomcat

Comment: Could you add the output from openssl command: openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443

Comment: connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=111.This was the output.

Comment: Please reply...

Comment: Please see the Apache configuration documents. I am empty of idea's, I am sorry. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File